# the construction birth X with Y

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language

> This magic spell will birth a new world with many people.

Does this mean that the magic spell will create a new world and also create many people along the way, or does this mean that the magic spell and the people will create a new world? How do you say the former if it doesn't mean that?

Comment: Is it something you made up, or is there a source?

Comment: It's completely made up

Comment: Then what did you mean to say by it?

Comment: I thought you could substitute with with and, but I am pretty sure this is wrong. I am just wondering if there's another way to say this without using and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

> The magic spell and the people will create a new world.

As that is correct English.

Your use of birth is not idiomatic.  Perhaps you should use "give birth to"

> This magic spell will give birth to a new world with many people.

But the meaning of this is different. This means

> The magic spell will create a new world, and the magic spell will create many people in that world.

So perhaps you want

> The magic spell and the people will give birth to a new world.

Comment: _Birth_ can be used for _give birth to_ (though I personally dislike the usage). I wonder whether the OP means '_for_ many people'?